# Unable to fetch list of files using jsch in java, to remote server's directory

Tags: java, remote-server, jsch

I am trying to populate files to a remote server using jsch library. The directory structure is like '/home/myname/batch_run_dt=20180706/batchid=P20180706001/* '

so the base directory, ***batch_run_dt***, contains multiple sub directories (batchid=P20180706*), and further those have files. The structure is to be maintained in the similar manner in remote server. I am using below piece of code to implement this functionality.

```
    public class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException, JSchException {
    Date todaydate = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(todaydate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);


 SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

 String date = ft.format(cal.getTime());
    logger.info("date :: " + date);
    // starting the process

        String partition = "batch_run_dt=" + date;
        getData(partition);
}    
 public static void getData(String partition)       throws JSchException {
    logger.info("Starting download data ");
    // get the destination location
    String destLoc = "/home/myname/" + partition;

    // get source location from data needs to import through sftp
    String srcLoc = "/home/myname/" + partition;

    download(partition, prop, destLoc, srcLoc);
    logger.info("Finished download prov data ");
}

public static void download(String partition, Properties prop, String destLoc, String srcLoc) throws JSchException {

    // creaating a sesssion for jsch
    Session session = NonProdRunner.createjschsession("username",
            "password", "host");
    // creating a channel from session
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    // creating sftp channel to connect
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    // create file object
    File dir = new File(destLoc);

    // check if file exists if exists, means we already have data
    // else create directory structure
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    } else {
        logger.error("File already exist");
        new Exception("Destination already Exists");
    }

    logger.info("Created destination folders");

    // get all the files
    mget(channelSftp, srcLoc, destLoc);
    // close connection and session
    channelSftp.exit();
    session.disconnect();
    System.out.println("session disconnected");

}

private static Session createjschsession(String uname, String pwd, String host) throws JSchException {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(uname, host);
    session.setPassword(pwd);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    logger.info("Connecting Session");
    session.connect();
    logger.info("Connected Session");
    return session;

}

private static void mget(ChannelSftp channelSftp, String srcLoc, String destLoc) {
    try {
        // Setting the folder location of the external system as
        // configured
        // to download the file from
        logger.info("src loation :: " + srcLoc);
        channelSftp.cd(srcLoc);
        channelSftp.lcd(destLoc);
        logger.info("folder changed");
        Vector<LsEntry> dirlist = channelSftp.ls("*");
        logger.info("Got list of remote files");
        for (LsEntry entry : dirlist) {

            Vector<LsEntry> batchID = channelSftp.ls("*");


            for (LsEntry batchEntry : batchID) {

                String filename = batchEntry.getFilename();
                logger.info("Loading BatchID: " + filename);

                File dir = new File(destLoc+"/"+filename);
                dir.mkdirs();

                logger.info(destLoc+"/"+filename);
                System.out.println(destLoc+"/"+filename);

                channelSftp.cd(filename);

                logger.info("Entered into: " + filename);

                Vector<LsEntry> files = channelSftp.ls(srcLoc+"/"+filename+"/*");
                for (LsEntry file: files) {

                    logger.info(file.getFilename());

                    String partFiles = file.getFilename();

                    channelSftp.get(partFiles, destLoc+"/"+filename);//.get(partFiles, partFiles);

                }
            }

        }
        logger.info("File copy done");

    } catch (SftpException sftpException) {
        logger.error("Exception in sftp: " + sftpException.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

}

but I am getting an error after the very first sub-folder is loaded that ***Exception in sftp: No such file*** . Not sure what I am missing here, Please help in resolving this.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve], this is unclear on what part this is failing.

Comment: @AxelH actually its in the sub-folder, batch_run_dt base directory follows the format, batch_run_dt=yyyyMMdd

Comment: so it fails when it is done loading the first subdirectory and trying to load the files of second subdirectory, i.e. after **System.out.println(destLoc+"/"+filename)**

Comment: I am trying to access batchid folder . Tried  as per your suggestion, and got the mentioned logs, shared in next comment

Comment: **2018-07-09 12:44:31 INFO  com.runners.NonProdRunner - folder changed
2018-07-09 12:44:31 INFO  com.runners.NonProdRunner - Got list of remote files
2018-07-09 12:44:31 INFO  com.runners.NonProdRunner - Loading BatchID: batchid=P20180708059
2018-07-09 12:44:31 INFO  com.runners.NonProdRunner - /home/myname/batch_run_dt=20180708/batchid=P20180708059
2018-07-09 12:44:31 ERROR com.runners.NonProdRunner - Exception in sftp:/home/myname/batch_run_dt=20180708/batchid=P20180708059/* is not unique: (Further it contains list of all files in this directory with their absolute paths)**

Comment: I have already post the answer that andwer your problem from the information I have. If you want a more specific answer, I will need a [mcve], this means that the code should be reduce to what fails, the information on the folder server should be provided and of course, get ride of those loops to provide a simple "cd" on the folder failing. This should be a good start. But all that can only be done by you since this is specificly failing on the structure you vaguely explained. PS: use the [edit] feature. I will get back to you when I am done cooking ;) **PS2: add the full stacktrace**

Comment: Why do you do download/get, when you want to *"populate files to a remote server"* (what imo means upload/put)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `ls *` you will get either file and folder and then you use that to `cd filename`.

Possibility :

- this is a file
- the user don't have the correct right

Check the documentation to confirm the problem :

[`ChannelSftp.cd`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#cd-java.lang.String-)

> SftpException - if the named path does not indicate a directory, if it is not accessible by the user, or some other problem occurs.

One of the other problem possible is if you try to moove into a folder like :

```
cd /root/folder*
```

where the structure propose more than one result :

```
/root/folderA
/root/folderB
```

Since the command could give to result : `folderA` and `folderB`, you will get an exception :

```
Exception in sftp:/root/folder* is not unique:
```